# How to Resolve Magento 1.7.0.2 error related to customer?

Tags: magento

I’ve a problem with Magento 1.7.0.2 (upgraded from 1.7.0.1 fresh install) :

1. When a customer register, he cannot login anymore. Everytime the
   customer tries to login, he login page reloads.
2. When I try to edit a customer from the admin panel, I get the following error:

   ```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function setDisabled() on a non-object in /home/***/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line 83
   ```
3. When I try to add a new customer from the admin panel, I get the
       following error:

   ```
    Fatal error:  Call to a member function addClass() on a non-object in /home/***/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php on line 87
   ```

I have seen already some forums messages about this, and tried multiples proposed solutions, but none of them is working.

It’s really urgent for me to solve this issue, because if we cannot edit customers, of if customers cannot login, I can forget to launch my ecommerce website using Magento. It won’t work as expected…

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it has to do with the associated website id... perhaps you have changed around the website IDs and now the system cannot find what site the suers are (were) associated with? The fatal errors you describe have to do with the website_id not being a valid object, meaning perhaps the id is not found.

I am assuming you remembered to clear cache and reindex after the upgrade to 1.7.0.2.

Good luck!

Comment: hello ! Thanks for your answer. I cleared the cache and reindexed everything of course. I did several tests by adding users from the front end by myself, and didn't change website id in the meantime. The problem still occurs.

Comment: I checked again, and the website id is correctly setup int the customer informations.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to copy the `'mag_customer_eav_attribute'` from 
a clean magento installation int my `mag_customer_eav_attribute` there seems to be a Problem with the data.